# Swift CoreData predicate

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, predicate

I'm quite new to programming in swift and have recently begun experimenting with persistent data. I have a problem with predicates for search requests.

My (test) application is a simple grade manager. It has `Course` entities that have a one-to-many relationship with `Grade` entities. When I want to display my grades in a tableview I want to fetch all grades that have a relation with a specific course. I made a function for this in my `DatabaseController` class (which I use to manage my CoreData), but when you actually fetch the return value of this function it's always empty.

```
class func returnFetchRequestGrades(course: Course) -> NSFetchRequest<Grade>{

    let fetchRequestGradesInCourse: NSFetchRequest<Grade> = Grade.fetchRequest()
    let predicateCourse = NSPredicate(format: "%@ == %@", "c.course.courseName", course)
    fetchRequestGradesInCourse.predicate = predicateCourse

    return fetchRequestGradesInCourse
}
```

What can I do to solve this?

It does work when I use the following work-around: I create a fetch request without a predicate. I fetch the result. This gives me back a list of all grades. I then (using a for-loop) pick out all the correct grades.

Comment: Use "%K" for key substitution. Example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638253/1187415

Answer (score 0):

Is courseName a value for the Grade entity? If so your predicate might be wrong, try:

`let predicateCourse = NSPredicate(format: "courseName == %@", course)`