# reason: 'Unable to parse the format string "a:CountyName = %@"'

Tags: ios, swift, nspredicate

When I using NSPredicate format for searching the value from array I got this issue but I unable to fix, please help me for fix the issue.

Here I post the code what I am trying..

```
var getCounty = NSArray() 
var arrCountyFilterData = NSArray()

let predicate: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "a:CountyName contains[c] %@",text);
    let predicateSecond: NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "text contains[c] %@",text)
    let predicateCompound = NSCompoundPredicate.init(type: .or, subpredicates: [predicate,predicateSecond])
    arrCountyFilterData = self.getCounty.filter { predicateCompound.evaluate(with: $0) } as NSArray;
    showSearchCountyResults = true
```

The getCounty array is:

```
getCounty is: (
    {
    "a:CaDId" =         {
        text = 3;
    };
    "a:CountyName" =         {
        text = Anderson;
    };
},
    {
    "a:CaDId" =         {
        text = 241;
    };
    "a:CountyName" =         {
        text = Andrews;
    };
},
    {
    "a:CaDId" =         {
        text = 4;
    };
    "a:CountyName" =         {
        text = Angelina;
    };
},
    {
    "a:CaDId" =         {
        text = 5;
    };
    "a:CountyName" =         {
        text = Aransas;
    };
})
```

Comment: Why bother use predicate with swift? Use `filter` instead

Comment: how, can you explain please..?

Comment: realm won't understand a: properly. you may need to escape it

Comment: Use  `%K` substitution for the key, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638253/1187415 for an example.