# Swift Core Data NSPredicate static string issue

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspredicate

I would like to make predicate more flexible for changes. I have lot of such strings in the sources code:

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "bodyPart.name = %@", name)

let filteredExercises = ExerciseEntity.mr_findAll(with: predicate)
```

but as you see if I will change BodyPart name to MuscleGroup for example someday it will cause issue like:

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'keypath bodyPart.name not found in entity <NSSQLEntity ExerciseEntity id=5>'
```

I am searching for the solution with a key paths like

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%@ = %@", \BodyPart.name, name)
```

Comment: Compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638253/1187415.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use %K to substitute the key path

```
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", #keyPath(BodyPart.name), name)
```

Comment: It should be `#keyPath(BodyPart.name)`, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/41638253/1187415

Comment: it will just return "name == some name" but I need "bodyPart.name", for sure I can combine to strings I guess) thanks

good solution!

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander: You can build arbitrary key paths, e.g. `#keyPath(ExerciseEntity.bodyPart.name)` if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I guess there is a difference here between Bodypart and bodypart, one is an entity and the other a relationship?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yea I have exercise with a bodyPart which and there is a relationships between two this objects

I written smh like this based on your example:

```let keyPath = #keyPath(ExerciseEntity.muscle) + "." + #keyPath(MusclEntity.name)
            
            let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K = %@", keyPath, muscleName)```

not sure if this is good or not

Sorry changed name already bodypart->muscle

Comment: @MatrosovAlexander, shouldn't it be like Martin R suggests above `#keyPath(ExerciseEntity.muscle.name)`?

Comment: @JoakimDanielson yea awesome, thanks guys! really helpful, I am super satisfied!